# Generic design for custom Table

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

Forgive me if there are syntax problems. The goal of this is not to get the code perfect but to get the design.

I have an `interface ITable<T>`

```
public interface ITable<T> {
    public Collection<T> getEntries();
    public void add(CustomObj value);
    public Collection<CustomObj> getCustomObjects();
}
```

that is used by two classes:

`TableOne<CustomObj>` and `TableTwo<Pair<CustomObj, CustomObj>>`

Then I have an interface that applies these tables using a function

```
public interface ITableFunction<T> {
    public abstract Collection<ITable<?>> execute(Collection<ITable<T>> tables);
}
```

My dilemma occurs when I try to create a generic Abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractTableFunctionCombined<T> implements ITableFunction<T>{
    private boolean someBool;
    public AbstractTableFunctionCombined(boolean someBool){
        this.someBool = someBool;
    }
    @Override
    public Collection<ITable<?>> execute(Collection<ITable<T>> tables){
        // What i would like to do, but can't right now:
        ITable<T> combinedTable;
        if (someBool){
            combinedTable = new TableOne();
        } else {
            combinedTable = new TableTwo();
        }
        for(ITable<T> table : tables){
            combinedTable.addAll(table.getCustomObjects());
        }
        for(T entry : table.getEntries()){
            execute(entry);
        }
    }
    public abstract void execute(T entry);

}
```

The issue is that I can't guarantee that the type `T` is the same as the table that I'm trying to instantiate. I thought I had to create some kind of relationship from the `Pair<CustomObj, CustomObj>` and the regular `CustomObj`. I tried creating a `Entry` interface that these both would use, and having `ITable<T>` be `ITable<T extends Entry>` but again this runs into the same problem.

I also thought that maybe I can make the `TableOne` and `TableTwo` classes use the same Generic i.e. `TableTwo<T> implements ITable<T>`, but TableTwo has a hard restriction of using `Pair<CustomObj, CustomObj>`.

Would I have to create two separate classes: `AbstractTableFunctionOne<CustomObj>` and `AbstractTableFunctionTwo<Pair<CustomObj, CustomObj>>` ? I would like to avoid this as it would be a lot of duplicated code.

Or am I over forcing this Object oriented design? Should TableOne and TableTwo not even implement the same interface?

Answer (score 0):

This Interface has some issus:

```
public interface ITableFunction {
    public abstract execute(Collection<ITable<T>> tables);
}
```

You need a return type and a Generic:

```
public interface ITableFunction<T> {
    public abstract void execute(Collection<ITable<T>> tables);
}
```

and return type of Method

```
public Collection<ITable<T>> execute(Collection<ITable<T>> tables){
..
```

should be Collection OR void in declaration AND implementation.

Comment: that's one of the "Forgive me if there are any syntax problems" sorry for that. I'm trying to condense code to simple example